# Automatically reopen files in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

I work with many different files in LibreOffice Writer at the same time. When I turn my computer off, I need to close them all, and later open them again, one by one. Isn't there an add-on or something that automatically saves all open documents and reopens them automatically later? Even better if it could save in a temp folder even the unsaved drafts.